# Can't Implicitly Convert "string" to generic type <T>

Tags: .net, generics

We have following classes

```
public class MyPropertyBase
{
    public int StartOffset { get; set; }
    public int EndOffset { get; set; }
}

public class MyProperty<T> : MyPropertyBase
{
    public MyProperty(T propertyValue)
    {
        PropertyValue = propertyValue;
    }

    public T PropertyValue { get; set; }
}

class BE
{
    public MyProperty<string> FUND_CITY { get; set; }

    public MyProperty<int> SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }

    public List<MyPropertyBase> MyDataPoints { get; set; }
}
```

When I create instance of `BE` as `objBE` and assign `objBE.FUND_CITY="Some Value"` it gives the error:

> "Can't convert "string" to MyProperty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. `FUND_CITY` is not a `string`, but is a `MyProperty<string>` type. You'll need to do:

```
objBE.FUND_CITY = new MyProperty<string>("Some Value").
```

Or, if you have a parameterless constructor, you can do:

```
objBE.FUND_CITY = new MyProperty<string>();
objBE.FUND_CITY.PropertyValue = "Some Value";
```

Answer (score 3):

This occurs because the `FUND_CITY` member of the `BE` instance `objBE` is of type `MyProperty<string>` and not `string` so you are trying to assign a value to the wrong type.

You could do:

```
objBE.FUND_CITY.PropertyValue = "Some Value";
```

and that might yield the result you were looking for otherwise to set that member directly you could do something like below.

```
objBE.FUND_CITY = new MyProperty<string>("Some Value");
```

or if you want to use implicit typing..

```
objBE.FUND_CITY = new MyProperty("Some Value");
```

Comment: Compile time error removed. But it it give run time error: {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Comment: @user1043788 Yes this will happen if you try to assign a value to `PropertyValue` on `FUND_CITY` without ever initializing the `FUND_CITY` property on the `BE` object (it is a null reference.) So you could do this in the initializer for the `BE` type or you could use one of the alternate examples posted, I suggest the implicit typed example if you decide not to implement the implicit operator design change suggested by @leppie.

Answer (score 3):

If you want that syntax, you need an implicit conversion.

Example:

```
public class MyProperty<T> : MyPropertyBase
{
    public MyProperty(T propertyValue)
    {
        PropertyValue = propertyValue;
    }

    public T PropertyValue { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator MyProperty<T>(T t)
    {
       return new MyProperty(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is definitely a much more efficient way of resolving this question. I would also like to point out that you can create an implicit conversion from type "MyProperty" to type T which also gives you assignment back from the property. This essentially makes the property transparent when you don't need any of it's special functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Try objBE.FundCity = new MyProperty("SomeValue");

Answer (score 0):

With your current design, you'll need to write

```
objBE.FUND_CITY.PropertyValue = "Some Value";
```

This is because the `FUND_CITY` property of `BE` isn't a `string`, it's a `MyProperty<string>` which itself has a property called `PropertyValue`.